# Is it possible to increase digital color depth via interpolation?

Tags: color, color-management, bit-depth

I have a set of photos that where scanned at 8 bit color depth. Is it possible to increase the color depth digitally? I realize just increasing the color depth would gain me nothing unless it also interpolated similar to increasing a photo's pixels.

Any software tools for this? I am using a mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to increase colour depth? Colour depth has little to do with how intense, or how vibrant the colours look, only with transitions between similar colours.

To put it another way the main consequence of having a low colour depth is the appearance of banding or posterization in smooth colour transitions.

Increasing the colour depth on it's own does nothing to alleviate banding, as 8 bit values like 1010 0111 are simply replaced with 16 bit values like 1010 0111 0000 0000, which is essentially the same number but using more bits.

You can't use interpolation as there's nothing to interpolate between. You could use smoothing but that wont do anything to reduce the appearance of banding as most displays are 8bit devices anyway.

However you can add noise to effectively randomise the low order bits that otherwise get set to zero. And doing so does fight the appearance of banding, which is the only reason I can see to increase the colour depth, hence that's the answer to your question:

**Yes, you can increase colour depth, but by adding noise, not interpolating.**

Comment: "You can't use interpolation as there's nothing to interpolate between." Ok, I can see that and this is similar to what @fortran suggests. It seems that there would be value in adding color depth before making changes to color/exposure.... or is this not true?

Comment: @Vincent increasing colour depth before making multiple image colour/contrast adjustments will certainly prevent any additional posterization or banding occurring.

Comment: If one did convert and interpolate an 8-bit image into a 16-bit image, then added noise in the lower levels, the increase in bit depth should then be valuable. You would lose detail, but you would reduce or eliminate the chance of adding posterization (or other artifacts) during any further editing after the conversion.

Answer (score 6):

You can increase the colour depth at expense of reducing the spatial resolution.

I.e. if you downsample the image 50% on each axis, you can get 2 extra bits of colour depth.

Is it worth? I doubt it...

Comment: Two extra bits can be very meaningful. If you have only 8 bits of color, and add two more, your color depth increases from 16.7 million colors to **over 1 billion colors**. There are certainly caveats to that...most screens can only display 8-bit color anyway, and screens that can display 10-bit color tend to be expensive, and require special software setups and calibration hardware. Whether the increase in bit depth is USEFUL could be debatable, however that does not diminish the value of having an extra two bits of color depth.

Comment: Remember that every new digit (bit) in binary increases the available numeric range by a factor of two. When it comes to color, since there are three components in RGB, that increase is compounded.

Comment: Would this really be a meaningful gain?  You're dealing with cropped values already in the pixels that you are blending, so I would challenge you are not actually getting 2 bits more of color depth, at-least not in a meaningful way compared to the original scene.

Comment: @jrista What I meant is that the image loses information with the process... 4 8-bit-per-channel pixels hold more information than a single 10-bit-per-channel pixel.

Comment: @AJHenderson Well, it depends on the textures (if there's moire for example), resolution of the lens... But if it works for noise reduction, I don't see why it shouldn't work for adding an extra bit or two of information.

Comment: @fortran - It works for noise reduction because it reduces the available information to average noise across signal.  For color depth, the rounding error is already taken by the initial truncation.  A rounding of a combination of two rounded values that are already error isn't going to have a meaningful relationship to real life.  It will produce more colors, but they aren't going to be any more accurate than the originally captured image, thus no (or minimal) additional information will be gleaned unless I'm missing something about the math.

Comment: Noise, dynamic range, bits...depending on how you look at it, it's all the same thing. Ironically, another way to improve detail/bit depth/dynamic range in an image is to add noise to the lower order bits, and not downscale (interpolate) at all. It really depends on your ultimate goals, and I did state that there are definite caveats (which I think pertain to the crux of the question)...but there should be no denying that two extra bits ultimately means you have a significantly broader range of representable values. The value of that would be improved editing latitude...less chance of...

Comment: ...artifacts occurring if you perform further editing on the image after downsampling. This improved editing latitude could be very important if you have a significant amount of editing to perform on a scanned photo...you may not be able to actually SEE that benefit on screen if you don't have an adequate monitor with a 10bit to 16bit LUT (i.e. an 8bit screen may still SHOW posterization, even if it does not actually exist in the underlying data.)

Comment: @AJHenderson Considering that there are always sampling errors (even at low ISO), statistically speaking you can get a value closer to the real value by averaging... Let's say that the 'real' value in a region that is almost black is 0.3/255; the sensor could yield 1/255 one out of four times and 0/255 the other three; if we downsample those 4 pixels we'd get a value of 0.25/255, which is closer to the real value than any of the individual pixels.

Comment: @jrista oddly, a few months ago I had an idea to take advantage of downsampling preserving the extra bits in colour depth: to do HDR tonemapping in phones that do not support RAW. But I had the hunch that it would be mostly equivalent to do the tonemapping in the 8-bit high-res picture and then downsampling afterwards to reduce artifacts.

Comment: @fortran - yes, it may get slightly closer, but it's also possible that it was actually a change in texture that would be lost.  The overall resolution is dropped and the information gained is still not necessarily accurate even if it is preserving some of the lost resolution in the form of better color depth.  I would say it is more preserving some of the lost data than truly increasing the color depth.  The gain will be marginal compared to an image captured natively at that resolution with the target color depth.

Comment: @AJHenderson: Sure, downsampling won't increase any intrinsic data. As I said, the primary reason to convert to a higher bit depth and downsample would be to increase your **editing latitude**. You will not see any increase in detail, and not necessarily any actual increase in IQ in general. What you will get is more freedom to tweak settings without causing unsightly artifacts that arise from the editing process (especially destructive editing processes.) That is, in general, the primary reason to have more bits anyway, whether you capture them natively or convert and downsample.

Comment: @jrista - yeah, I'm not arguing against that and I think I mentioned it as a benefit in my answer, but you can get that by simply adding a 0 bit in the new least significant digit without having to take a resolution loss.  (Hmm, I hadn't mentioned why you would want to in my answer after all.  Guess I thought it but didn't write it.  I updated to include it.)

Comment: @AJHenderson: A zero bit...or better, just add a little bit of noise to the lower order bits. A small amount of noise has the effect of improving dynamic range (or what ctein would insist is actually "exposure range": http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2012/09/dynamic-range-is-not-exposure-range-part-ii.html).

Comment: @jrista - I'd point out that the exposure range doesn't actually change as the brightest and darkest points remain the brightest and darkest, just the number of distinct values in between is increased which is also subtly different.  And I suppose local pixel sample based noise for setting the least order bit would work well even if it might ever so slightly soften the image.

Comment: @AJ: Exactly...hence the value of increased bit depth. You get more levels, the only way to really use them is to do something to the image...interpolate (like you mentioned in your answer)...or add noise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you gain nothing. If you have two neighbouring pixels of intensity 128 and 127, the new interpolated one (between those two) will have an intensity of 127.5. This way you increased color depth (value 127.5 can't be stored in 8bits, but "can" in 9 bits - as value 255).
If you interpolate more pixels, you must increase color depth more - double the dimension = add additional bit.

All stated above is valid for linear interpolation only. If you use (and you should) some more complex interpolations (bicubic etc.), you get intensity values that are more precise. But they must be rounded to fit into defined color depth.

Comment: Is @fortran correct that this is only possible if the image is down scaled? Its not clear to me how using bicubic.. one would choose to change a pixles value. By that I mean this would seem to blur the color. Is this an improvement? Do you know of any examples of this being done or how I could test this?

Comment: There are two very similar ways to look at it. You can downsample or upsample. I choose upsample, because you mentioned it in Q. Downsample on my example: You have two pixels, 128 and 127. By downsampling you will get one pixel of their "average" (when it is linear), thus 127.5. The rest is the same.
For more information on interpolation look on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation
You will see that in case of polynomial you won't get average value between two sample values but something very different.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file format and map the original values to their new levels, but it won't more accurately reflect the original image since the data from the original is lost.  Simply changing formats is a relatively simple linear operation (add one or more 0 bits to the right side of each value and update the color space).  The main advantage of this is that it will remove rounding error resulting in further loss.

You could also try to reduce the resolution of the image (or simply use neighboring pixels) to blend pixels together to get values spread out over the new range, but again, these have no basis in the original image being captured, they are simply made up values.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the representation of the colour depth would do little to help you but there are plenty of options to improve the image you have.  As you're on a mac the obvious first place to start is iPhoto, but there also online tools like [pixlr](http://pixlr.com) which would allow you to tweak the contrast levels and colours quickly and simply.

Comment: I understand that but at the end of the day it is still 8 bit. I guess I would just like to see for myself that "Increasing the representation of the colour depth would do little to help" ;-)

Comment: It's a case of simple maths, think of the bits as a percentage rather than a real number.  If you have something that is 50% bright, representing it as 50.00% adds 2 significant figures to the accuracy but doesn't actually do anything to change the underlying value.